# What is the real name for the initial object in the category of "monoid-valued measures of intervals" on transitive relations?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, graph-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

(I'm not asking for a true/false answer; I have a true algebraic fact and I'm looking for a reference in the literature. By the way, there is a version of this theorem that replaces monoid with $R$-module, monoid multiplication with module addition, and monoid homomorpism with $R$-linear transformation where $R$ is a commutative ring.)

Let $G$ be a set and $E$ a transitive non-empty binary relation on $G$. (Note: to obtain such a relation from any directed graph, just take the transitive closure of the edges.) Let $F_0 = \langle (g,h)\colon g\,E\,h \wedge g,h\in G\rangle = \langle E \rangle$ be the free monoid generated by the edges, and let $\sim$ be the congruence on $F_0$ generated by $(g,i)\sim(g,h)(h,i)$ for all $g,h,i\in G$ such that $(g,i),(g,h),(h,i)\in E$. Let $F=F_0/\sim$ be the *interval monoid* for $E$.

Let $G$ be a set, $E$ a transitive non-empty binary relation on $G$, and $W$ a monoid. An *interval measure* on $(G,E)$ taking values in $W$ is a map $I\colon E\rightarrow W$ such that $I(g,h)\,I(h,i)=I(g,i)$ for all $g,h,i\in G$ and $(g,h),(h,i),(g,i)\in E$.

The following theorem says that the interval monoid is the initial object in the category with objects the interval measures and morphisms the measure-preserving monoid homomorphisms. (A morphism of interval measures $(W,I)$ to $(V,J)$, $\varphi\colon W\rightarrow V$, must be both a monoid homomorphism and satisfy $J(g,h)=\varphi(I(g,h))$ for all $g,h\in G$.)

Theorem. Let $G,E$ and $F$ be as above. For every monoid $W$ and interval measure $I$ on $(G,E)$ taking values in $W$, there exists a unique monoid homomorphism $J\colon F\rightarrow W$ such that $J(s,t)=I(s,t)$ for all $(s,t)\in E$.

Proof. (Almost trivial.)

Comment: People would usually associate to a transitive relation the semigroup where you make zero any product not in the relation and have a 0

Comment: What are the elements of the semigroup?

Comment: The elements are pairs $(g,h)$ in the relation and a zero.  Then the product if $(g,h)(k,l)=(g,l)$ if $h=k$ and 0 else and of course zero is a multiplicative zero.  This is the quotient of your monoid by a certain ideal (except that I didn't include the identity).

Comment: In all honesty though I think you should work with the semigroupoid (or semi-category) with objects $G$ and arrows $E$ where $(g,h)$ goes from $h$ to $g$ and the product is as you defined above.  Then your interval measures are functors from this semigroupoid to the monoid (viewed as a one-object semigroupoid) and you don't have to worry about the issue that you interval measures aren't really homomorphisms.

Comment: O.K. So (1) the elements of any transitive relation form a semigroupoid according to the product you defined, and (2) an interval measure is really a semigroupoid homomorphism. Every semigroupoid homomorphism with domain a transitive relation and codomain a monoid factors through the interval monoid. The elements in the category are then pairs, monoids together with homomorphisms (index map) from a fixed semigroupoid to the monoid, and the morphisms are monoid homomorphisms that commute with the index maps. Only one term remains: what is the real name for "interval monoid"?

Comment: These are special subsemigroups of Brandt monoids.  I don't know if they have a name.

Comment: Given a semigroupoid $S$, does the category of objects $(W,\varphi)$ where $W$ is a monoid and $\varphi\colon S\rightarrow W$ is a homomorphism and morphisms $\psi\colon W\rightarrow W'$ monoid homomorphisms such that $\varphi'=\psi\circ\varphi$ have an initial element?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the monoid with generators the arrows of the semigroupoid and relations the products in the semigroupoid.

Comment: Yes. That's what the interval monoid is. I didn't realize the common definition of semigroupoid is "small category minus identity maps" as opposed to "semigroup with partial multiplication". So I intended to ask a different question. In fact, I've yet to see an author define any term as "semigroup with partial multiplication".

Comment: I would say partial semigroup

Comment: The "semigroup with partial multiplication" won't work since it may be the case that $ab$, $(ab)c$, and $bc$ exist while $a(bc)$ does not; apparently there isn't a definition where I expected to find one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Partial semigroups don’t have a uniformly agreed on definition because people want different interpretations of which products force others to exist